# iphone sdk - Remove all characters except for numbers 0-9 from a string

Tags: iphone, nsstring

OK So here's the plan. The XML I'm getting data from allows non-numeric text in phone number fields (for descriptions or contact names, etc). I am trying to extract only the numbers and call the tel: URL with them to initiate a call. Here's whats NOT working:

```
NSCharacterSet *charset = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
NSString *number = @"(555) 555-5555 Office";
NSString *strippedNumber = [number stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charset];
NSString *phoneURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", strippedNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneURL]];
```

if there are any obvious typos, they're just typos. :)

Comment: take easy NSString * phoneNumberString = @”(555) 555-5 !@#$%^&*()}{|:><‘?/.,’;][’55 Office”;

NSString *pureNumbers = [[phoneNumberString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@“”];

NSLog(@”%@”,pureNumbers);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using a trim method, which means that it's only looking at the outer edges of the string.  You're probably getting something like:  "555) 555-555" as the phone number, correct?

I'm not aware of an NS(Mutable)String method along the lines of "replaceOccurrencesOfCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set", and I admit, that'd probably be really nice to have.

Being me, I'd probably just use a regex.  If you use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net), then you can easily do:

```
#import "RegexKitLite.h"

NSString * number = @"(555) 555-555 Office";
NSString * strippedNumber = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"[^0-9]" withString:@""];
```

It might be a bit overkill, but it will do exactly what you're looking for.

FYI: "[^0-9]" means "any character that's not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9".

Comment: RegexKitLite is a little outdated regarding ARC and iOS 6. Please check my answer to see a method that works without this library.

Answer (score 94):

Simpler using iOS APIs only:

```
NSString * number = @"(555) 555-555 Office";
NSString * strippedNumber = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [number length])];
```

Answer (score 12):

Although this has already been answered/accepted, I have a better solution without needing an external SDK.  Create an additional NSString method in a category like this:

```
@interface NSString (Helpers)

- (NSString*)stringByRemovingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet*)set;

@end

@implementation NSString (Helpers)

- (NSString*)stringByRemovingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet*)set
{
    NSArray* components = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
    return [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}

@end
```

Now you can use stringByRemovingCharactersInSet instead of stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet. However I'd also recommend another slight change to your example code, to support the '+' character in international numbers, as follows:

```
NSString* number = @"(555) 555-555 Office";
NSCharacterSet* phoneChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+0123456789"];
NSString* strippedNumber = [number stringByRemovingCharactersInSet:[phoneChars invertedSet]];
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", strippedNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```