# how to remove ( from string

Tags: iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone sdk - Remove all characters except for numbers 0-9 from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160403/iphone-sdk-remove-all-characters-except-for-numbers-0-9-from-a-string)

i have string with a phone number as

> mynumber = @"(334)687-6619";

I am using

```
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

to make a call.
But due to "(" , ")"  my method is not able to make a call.

Please suggest me to make a right string
something like

> "1-800-555-1212" or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: @CarlVeazey are you sure this is duplicate.. Other thread remove the '-' from the string too..

Comment: i got the result what i was expecting .

Comment: Oops.. @Carl Veazey u r right..

Answer (score 5):

You can Use

```
NSString *s = @"(334)687-6619";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"("];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"-"];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

So, It will replace "(" with "" & replace ")" with "-".

Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing it in two steps (which is itself superfluous), you don't even have to use character sets and the split-and-join trick, jnstead you can just use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.

Comment: Ok My friend, It's working. Question was about replacing string. So i've put.

Comment: s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"-"]; is also working. Thanks mate..:)

Comment: i think @iManan is right . it will work

Answer (score 3):

use this code

```
NSString *str = @"(334)687-6619";
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 1) withString:@"-"];    
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

**OUTPUT is:** 334-687-6619

Comment: Nice answer @paras joshi....

Answer (score 2):

To remove characters from a string:

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
NSArray *comps = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
NSString *newString = [comps componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```